# strange java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I tried to wrote a function who returns all of the txt files from some directory, that in the main I wrote:

```
File file = new File(dir);
listFiles(file.listFiles());
```

and the function is:

```
private static void listFiles(File[] files) {
        if (null == files)
            return;
        for (File file : files) {
            if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                if (file.getName().endsWith("txt") && file != null) {
                    queue.add(file);
                    fileCounter++;
                }
            } else {
                listFiles(file.listFiles());
            }
        }
    }
```

and every time it throw "java.lang.NullPointerException" in the "`queue.add(file);"

what is the problem?

Comment: maybe you didnt define `queue`? its just `null`. initiate it. `List<File> queue = new ArrayList<File>();` for example

Comment: It's not strange at all actually. You probably didn't initialize `queue` since you didn't post any such code. That's exactly what the exception is telling you btw. You should read up on exceptions before assuming you won't be able to solve them yourself.

Comment: And don't write `if(null == files)`, write `if(files == null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must instantiate your queue (`queue = new ...`) before you can actually add anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

This means `queue` is null - probably you didn't initialize it.